# Specifying a range when using barplot

Tags: r, plot

I want to use R to analyze my servers access log files. I'm new to R and want to use barplot to visualize the data. Is there a way with barplot to only plot values which occur x or more amount of times? At the moment I'm plotting requests to the server by frequency of occurrence however i'm only interested in requests that occurred for example 100 times or more. Is it possible to specify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a reproducible example, I am not sure of the answer. Here an example using `barchart` from the `lattice` package. I prefer it because if the handy formula notation. The idea here is to subset your data according to the criteria (Occurrence of the events here).

```
server= paste('EVENT_',sample(LETTERS[1:6],1000,rep=T),sep='')
dat <- as.data.frame(table(server))  ## I transform it to a data.frame for more flexibility
library(lattice)
p.160 <- barchart(Freq~server,data=subset(dat,Freq > 160),main='Event > 160')
p.all <- barchart(Freq~server,data = dat, main ='all events')
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p.all,p.160)
```

[image]